# Formula for calculating third point from two points and angle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, angle

[image: first angle]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to find angle of yellow line from center of circle. I know circle radius, red and blue point coordinates and angle between red and yellow lines.

What kind of formula should I use?

Comment: Given three points, A, B and C, you want to find the point on the line AB that is closest to C. Is that right?

Comment: It doesn't have to be on line, I need to find point close to C (if possible) but angle that all 3 points make must be in specified range.

Comment: Maybe question could be simplified, I need to calculate minimum and maximum allowed angle from bottom point that when I calculate middle point using angle in that range and fixed distance, angle between top middle bottom points is in requested range

Comment: Please put labels on points so we know what is what. The description is confusing to me.

Comment: Thank for the update in the question. As stated now, the orientation of the yellow line isn't defined because the red segment can stretch and expand. Also first you are asking for the angle of the yellow line (orientation), but then you want the angle of between red and yellow. Which one is it?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I know angle between red and yellow line it's fixed, yellow is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Think the situation is as follows:

[image: fig1]

Points **R** and **B** are given, as well as angle **θ**. What is asked for is angle **φ**.

I place a coordinate system on the center of the circle and expressed **R** in polar coordinates

```
d = sqrt( (x_R-x_B)^2 + (y_R-y_B)^2 )
ψ = atan2( (y_R-y_B), (x_R-x_B) )
```

Then use the [law of cosines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWAqt.png) to find **l**

```
l = sqrt(r^2 + d^2 -2*r*d*cos(θ))
```

Now to find **φ** and **ψ** we use the following two equations

```
d*cos(ψ) = r*cos(φ)-l*cos(θ-φ)
d*sin(ψ) = r*sin(φ)+l*sin(θ-φ)
```

This is where I am stuck now.

Comment: This looks close, but I don't know a. I have required angle at point p and I need to find angle between b and r. Is there version of this formula that can give a? Thanks

Comment: Can you please indicate what you know  (coords, lengths, angles), and what you want to calculate. Also what is fixed and what is varying.

Comment: I updated question with hopefully more clear details

Comment: Do you think that this might be unsolvable in way I need it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming the following are known:

- side `BC = a`
- radius `CA = b`
- angle `∡BAC = α`

It follows from the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) that `sin ∡ABC = AC sin ∡BAC / BC = b sin α / a`. The right-hand side is a known quantity, so the equation can be solved for `∡ABC` then the third angle of `△ABC` is `∡BCA = π - α - ∡ABC`. This gives the angle between the yellow line and the known segment `BC`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Assuming the vector length is the same, you could define the first point as the origin (0,0).
Then describe the first vector in polar coordinates, (r, \displaystyle \thetaθ), where \displaystyle r = \sqrt{x_{1 }^{2} + y_{1 }^{2}}r=
x
1
2
​
+y
1
2
​

​
and \displaystyle \thetaθ = \displaystyle arctan(y_{1 }/x_{1 })arctan(y
1
​
/x
1
​
).

Then create the second vector by adding k degrees to \displaystyle \thetaθ: \displaystyle \theta_{2 }θ
2
​
= \displaystyle \thetaθ + k
Then convert from polar coordinates back to rectangular coordinates--if you need them that way:

\displaystyle x_{2 } = r cos(\theta_{2 })x
2
​
=rcos(θ
2
​
) and
\displaystyle y_{2 } = r sin(\theta_{2 })y
2
​
=rsin(θ
2
​
)

Comment: Unfortunately [SO] does not support math formatting. Is there a way to format the above with code blocks and/or greek letters?